# Dagger can't @Inject some instances of same class

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, system.reactive, dagger

I ran into strange problem.
I need to inject two schedulers. For ui and async operations. I have RxModule class:

```
@Module
class RxModule {

@Named(Keys.SCHEDULER_UI)
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideUiScheduler(): Scheduler = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

@Named(Keys.SCHEDULER_ASYNC)
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAsyncScheduler(): Scheduler = Schedulers.io()
}
```

And I inject them into my presenter as

```
@Named(Keys.SCHEDULER_UI)
@Inject
lateinit var uiScheduler: Scheduler

@Named(Keys.SCHEDULER_ASYNC)
@Inject
lateinit var asyncScheduler: Scheduler
```

But Dagger falls down with exception:

```
io.reactivex.Scheduler cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method
```

Injections looks simple:

```
ApplicationLoader.instance.getApplicationComponent().inject(presenter)
```

My AppComponent:

```
@Component(modules = [RxModule::class, ApplicationModule::class, WebModule::class, RepositoryModule::class])
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(presenter: MainPresenter)
    fun inject(presenter: AppDetailsPresenter)
}
```

Does anyone faced the same issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So, after some time of researching I found solution. In Kotlin with @Inject while using @Named you should do this in other way. You inject should look like this:

```
@field:[Inject Named(Keys.SCHEDULER_UI)]
lateinit var uiScheduler: Scheduler
@field:[Inject Named(Keys.SCHEDULER_ASYNC)]
lateinit var asyncScheduler: Scheduler
```